# In Selenium python, unable to select radio elements in Modal

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on the radio button that comes from in MODAL but a timeout exception comes every time.

Here is the DOM element with a modal screenshot

[image: Here is the DOM element with a modal screenshot]

I'm using the PAGE OBJECT MODEL design pattern and below is the code. I'm trying to click through the main input locator and also select the main class.

Explitroy wait:

```
def get_element_clickable(self, by_locator):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(by_locator))
```

Call the locator in function:

```
    def get_select_radio(self):
        return self.get_element_clickable(self.Select_radio_button_of_modal)
```

Also, try this:

```
def get_element_clickable(self, by_locator):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(by_locator))
```

Can someone please help suggest to me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: How is _Select_radio_button_of_modal_ defined?

Comment: This is just the variable that store the locator value. Select_radio_button_of_modal = By.XPATH, "//input[@class='addRemoveEFAW' and @id='haveEfaw']"

Comment: See the footnote within [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70542264/in-selenium-python-unable-to-select-radio-elements-in-modal/70542350#70542350)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.addRemoveEFAW#haveEfaw"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='addRemoveEFAW' and @id='haveEfaw']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

PS: As you are using *PAGE OBJECT MODEL* the the within the respective *PageObject.py* page you have to define them accordingly.

Comment: Error found - TimeoutException: 

self = <selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait (session="270f2ba82ba15341038f858046246e35")>
method = <function element_to_be_clickable.<locals>._predicate at 0x0000025D7FEE4DC0>
message = ''

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Same error. I also try time.sleep() but not working.